# What unicode characters are best for drawing a squarewave in a string

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I am trying to represent a square wave pulse train in a string, from an array of stored GPIO events and timings. the code is working but I need better Unicode characters for the transitions.

this is my current method

```
    public String waveform()
    {
    String s = "";
    int pulses;
    int pulseWidth;

    pulseWidth = events.get(1).duration; //mostly right!
    for (RF433Event e: events)
    {
        pulses = e.duration/pulseWidth;
        if (e.gpioEvent.getEdge() == PinEdge.RISING)
        {
            // rising edge so for the duration it was low
            for (int i = 0; i<pulses; i++) s = s+'_';
            s = s+"\u02E9";
        } else
        {
            // falling edge so for the duration it was high
            for (int i = 0; i<pulses; i++) s = s+"\u0305";
            s = s+"\u02E5";
        }

    }
    return s;
    }
```

The output looks like this in the Intellij console window
[image]

but strangely is not appearing on the RPi, do I need to install something else on the Pi?

Comment: Maybe you need to install a font that supports the specific glyphs? Anyway, it may be better to use a character from that group: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F - or from that: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2300-23FF

Comment: The box characters work on the midpoint of the line so to do a reasonable square wave I would need to use 2 lines, which is not ideal. I think you are right about installing fonts though.

Comment: I added Unifont, this fixed the issue with no display in a terminal window, I am still looking for a suitable character to use though. I will keep looking.

Comment: Maybe there is none that perfectly fits the task. Sometimes, actually drawing it with graphics primitives is the right thing to do. Failing that, you could also go into the opposite direction and opt for a good-enough approximation with US-ASCII-only characters. (like _ | " or something)

Comment: Maybe a [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebook with the [tikzmagic extension](https://github.com/robjstan/tikzmagic) for [timing diagrams](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tikz-timing/) could be a drastically different but nice approach. (Disclaimer: I don't know if those diagrams are possible in tikzmagic.)

Answer (score 7):

After much experimentation this works for me

```
public String waveform()
{
    String s = "";
    int pulses;
    int pulseWidth;
    // Characters tried for drawing the pulse train
    // Low line - "_", "\u0332" Combining Low Line, "\uFF3F"; FULLWIDTH LOW LINE
    // High line - "\u0305" COMBINING OVERLINE, "\u203E" over line 
    // Vertical -  "\u20D2" COMBINING LONG VERTICAL LINE OVERLAY, "\u007C" Vertical line, "\u02E9" MODIFIER LETTER EXTRA-LOW TONE BAR
    if (events.get(0).duration > 50000) {return "Excessive duration in pluse 0 "+events.get(0).duration;}
    pulseWidth = 100; //gives a reasonable pulse train
    for (RF433Event e: events)
    {
        pulses = e.duration/pulseWidth;
        if (e.gpioEvent.getEdge() == PinEdge.RISING)
        {
            // rising edge so for the duration it was low
            for (int i = 0; i<pulses; i++) s = s+ "_";
            s = s+"\u20D2";
        } else
        {
            // falling edge so for the duration it was high
            for (int i = 0; i<pulses; i++) s = s+"\u0305";
            s = s+"\u20D2";
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

these are the results
[image: Pulse Trains]

Comment: I guess this is a niche problem, but as someone in that niche who may use this, I just wanted to say - great answer and thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of using "combining characters",
but find them harder to edit.
Here are other unicode options I've used or tried.

1. box drawings (light or heavy), which (as noted) need 2 rows:

```
1   ┌────┐      ┏━━━━┓
0 ──┘    └──  ━━┛    ┗━━
```

2. "lower one eighth block" (2581) with "lower three quarters block" (2586) or "full block" (2588). (Depending on font and line spacing, "full block" can reach the previous line.)

```
▁▆▆▆▁▁▇▇▁▁
▁▆▆▆▁▁▇▇▁▁
```

3. "solidus" (slash), "reverses solidus" (backslash), "horizontal scan line 1" (23BA), and "horizontal scan line 9" (23BD) - for non-vertical transitions.

```
⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺\⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽⎽/⎺⎺⎺⎺⎺\⎽⎽
```